# Playing Dailymotion videos in iPad

Tags: ipad, video, playing

I am developing an iPad application that lists News Videos from Dailymotion. I also want to play these news videos in my webview.

I tried playing the URL corresponding to the tag "media:player url=" in iPad. It does not work because iPad is not compatible with flash. Also, I tries embedding the code given as comment inside the tag media:player" in my HTMl code. But, still it does not work.

Could someone help me out. How to play Dailymotion videos in iPad

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, their content is only embeddable as a Flash object so you cannot play that on any Apple iPod/iPhone/iPad as they don't support Flash. You might want to try approaching DailyMotion to see if they are transcoding to H.264 (MP4) which you would be able to play.